# NextJS: how should subcomponents get data they need?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, next.js

If I have a page, with numerous sub components such as a Header that displays some account info, how do I best get the data for that component?

If i use componentDidMount and do a request to my laravel api, then there is a delay where the data should be until its loaded.

If I use getInitialProps then I have to have a endpoint for every page to get these details and then always have to pass it down.

Is there any other solutions that dont cause these 2 issues?

Comment: You are looking for state containers such as Redux or MobX. Check out the Next.js examples to get an idea: [with-mobx](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mobx), [with-redux](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux).

Answer (score 0):

For account level data that could be accessed on every page, I would write an HOC to wrap each account page that would fetch the user API data on the server-side so you are not waiting for anything on the client side. ( or at least minimize the wait time). This combined with a state controller like Redux or Mobx will be your best bet. So on first load your HOC will grab the data and store it on server-side. Then on every subsequent page request when navigating client-side, the data will already be there! Then you can write some logic into the HOC to make sure you're only making api requests on a page 'refresh', so your not making api calls everytime you route to another page.

Hope that helps!